# copy files into unknown directory

Tags: cmd

I want to copy a .txt file into an unknown folder. for example I have c:\report.txt and I want to copy it to c:\12345960. all these folders have only "960" the same. the other numbers changed by default. is there any way to copy some .txt to this directory from batch file?

Comment: You have only shown one folder.  It would help if you give some extra examples.

Comment: if there are several directories ending with `...960`, which one to choose?

Comment: ok lets simplify this. i have 10 pc with one folder that its name is ******960*. asteriscs in every pc is different. i want through batch file to copy/move some files(like txt or htm) into this directory.files stored in c:\ . also i want to move later this folder to my usb stick.(ps: in every pc there is one folder with ***960* name.)

Answer (score 1):

only one folder? That simplifies the problem:

```
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /b /ad c:\*960') do set dir=%%d
echo Directory name is: %dir%
rem copy "c:\report.txt" "c:\%dir%"
```

Comment: thank you. i thing this do not working. i put a pause and do not pause to see the error. if i put bat file in cmd window writes: \*960') was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Argh - my fault, I tried it on the commandline. For use in Batchfile, double the `%` in the `for`line. I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you my friend.i think its working. i'll try now to copy or move this folder or files into this folder.thank you again Stephan